# Time/date not auto recognising my location for time zone after using a VPN

Tags: macos, vpn, time, timezone

Recently I was using a VPN (provided by Avast) to secure my connection whilst traveling.

Right now I am not using it as I am back in my office.

But using it seems to have caused an issue with the auto time clock on my computer (see attached screenshot) any ideas how to resolve this?

[image: time preference page screenshot]

Comment: I don't think this is related to the fact that you have used a VPN recently. If you can try connecting to a different network or a public network it might be more likely to know where you are located, many business internet connections may not provide information on the location.

Comment: Thanks the reason i thought it might be to do with the VPN is i had my phone also connected to it, and it was causing my phone to be in the wrong time zone when abroad

Answer (score 0):

I hate to point out the obvious, but at least it is a temporary fix. Uncheck the "Set time zone automatically..." checkbox and manually set your time zone.